# How comes that this code hangs after 1 hour?

Tags: android

I am running this  code after every 30 second and after running app coninute 1 hour my phone and app hung up and i need to restart it again.

```
private void preventStatusBarExpansion(Context context) {

    WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) 

  context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

    Activity activity = (Activity) context;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
    localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
            // Draws over status bar
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

    localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int resId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    int result = 0;
    if (resId > 0) {
        result = activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resId);
    }

    localLayoutParams.height = result;

    localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;

    CustomViewGroup view = new CustomViewGroup(context);

    manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
}

public class CustomViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

public CustomViewGroup(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
}



 @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        Log.v("customViewGroup", "**********Intercepted");
        return true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're effectively calling the following calls every 30 seconds.

```
CustomViewGroup view = new CustomViewGroup(context);
manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
```

This creates and adds a view every 30 seconds, so it will surely scrape out the memory when being run for long durations. You should clearly remove the view once it is not required. Otherwise you're repeatedly stacking up the memory with the new views.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you in some way.